A haunted house with creepy people living
I'm trying to look for the movie that i watched a long time ago. I don't know the title as when I saw it on TV it was in the middle of the movie already. So the story goes like, there's a creepy house that once you are able to enter, it is imposible to go out as it was meant to imprison. The character i can remember, there's a guy who has a gun and a dog who was chasing the person who entered his house. There was also a creepy person who lived in the walls, i think he has some defect with his/her tongue. And there was prisoners under the house. I've been searching this for more than years already, but I didn't have any luck, as i have no clue what to search... i can't remember or recognize the actors/actress that was on the movie.
I hope someone here can figure what movie was i trying to describe. Thanks!

I think you are referring to The People Under the Stairs, IMDB link also.
This started with some kids who enter a house and are then pursued by a deranged brother/sister/man/wife, the brother wearing a creepy gimp outfit, the film played on the actors roles in Twin Peaks at the time if I remember correctly.
Links to some images

This sounds right to me.

Wow, yes, this was it... thank you! I finally found you :)
